# Как добавить .dll библиотеки SFML C++ в исходный .exe файл VisualStudio?

Tags: dll, include, exe, sfml

Как добавить библиотеки SFML C++ в исходный .exe файл VisualStudio?
Visual Studio Community 2017;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При указании дополнительных зависимостей, те же .dll добавить в графу "Свойства проекта => Компоновщик => Ввод => Внедрить управляемый файл ресурсов"
После компиляции мы получим файл содержащий в себе необходимые .dll

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]